# Build an Improved CRM dynamics 2011,13,15 Online Import Tool

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

Wanted to build an online import tool for CRM dynamics 2011,13,15.  It is not a tool to compete with Scribe or SSIS adapter. Rather it is tool to help the normal business users to use. Or data professional who wants to upload a small amount of data without using a big buck tool like scribe/ssis

First release will include following features on account/contact entity records only.

1. update parents record
2. support XLS xlsx (not XML format) uploads
3. support child parent record upload
4. allow users to test the first xx number of selected records
5. lookup matching for multiple matching criteria.

Do you think this idea would fly? or this is a bad business idea to start a cloud/online import tool based on dynamic CRM (as a start)?

Comment: Just curious. Inbuilt import was improved since time of 4.0. What are benefits of your solution comparing with it?

Comment: all of items above 1-5. Also, allow the business user to choose whether the field value can be updated (such as Update if different, update if the field is blank.. etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could give this a try because there are lot more features missing in OOB import for Dynamics CRM. Few of them could be,

1. Importing Subgrid data from the same xml file
2. Data import for N:N association

But I'm not sure whether users could pay for this. Most of their CRM developers have these sort of tools handy.